# How should we tag Space Invaders Infinity Gene?

Tags: discussion, tags

Yet another game with a tag longer than the 25 character limit. I'm having trouble figuring out how we should do this one. In our [past](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/how-should-we-tag-prince-of-persia) [discussions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-to-tag-the-need-for-speed-games) [regarding](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1995/how-should-we-tag-the-wonderful-end-of-the-world) titles with more than 25 characters, we seem to have come to a consensus of handling individually. I think. We don't really have an accepted answer on those first two, but in those cases, both of the series are well known enough to have their acronyms be fairly common.

Following the pattern we've shown so far, the options would be:

- `si-infinity-gene`

Precedent set in our Need For Speed series tagging, such as `nfs-hot-pursuit`. I don't think this is a very viable option in this case. "SI" as an acronym doesn't immediately connect to Space Invaders (at least for me) and as far as I know, has never really been used for the series.

- `space-invaders-ig`

Precedent set with the `assassins-creed-bh` tag for Assassin's Creed Brotherhood, but it's still a little unintuitive, though I suppose this is easily remedied by using the tag wiki (though we then run into the whole [dictionary vs. preface issue](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2208/how-do-we-prefer-to-start-our-tag-wikis)).

- `space-invaders-infinity`

Precedent set with `the-wonderful-end` for The Wonderful End of the World. This is the one I find myself leaning towards, even though it does drop the final word. I don't think we'll get *too* many people here asking for strategy on the original Space Invaders, but having the almost-full title at least helps with first-glance clarity and differentiation.

What do we think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire first page of a Google search for ["space invaders infinity"](http://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&nord=1&qscrl=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=space%20invaders%20infinity%20&qscrl=1&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d00794a945e60248&ion=1&biw=1059&bih=791) lists sites referring to Infinity Gene, so I don't think there will be any confusion if we use [space-invaders-infinity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-invaders-infinity) to refer to it.

I think first-glance clarity is the most important thing, and [space-invaders-infinity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-invaders-infinity) does a better job than [space-invaders-ig](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-invaders-ig) in that respect.

Comment: I agree, especially with the google visibility factor. I'll tag with this version.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Now that the maximum tag length has been [increased to 35](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've gone ahead and retagged the two questions about this game.

The tag name is now [space-invaders-infinity-gene](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-invaders-infinity-gene).

Answer (score 0):

Would it be plausible to make [infinity-gene](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinity-gene) with a Space Invaders icon? I know that icons are limited in [SO] to sponsored tags, but what about [gaming.se] ?

On the other hand, I think that [space-invaders-ig](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-invaders-ig) looks fine. (With capitals to show up that's acronym)
Does the game have an abbreviation like S2IG ?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no capitalization support for tags, so we wouldn't really be able to do that. Regarding the icon support, I've no idea how plausible that would be or if that would be supported here and there's no well known acronym for the game that I know of. I think the best bet is going with `space-invaders-infinity` if there are no further suggestions.

Comment: You can't search for an icon, and people would start typing space invaders, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @bwarner good point.